# Do I need to program BLEduino (arduino with BLE)?

Tags: xcode, arduino

I am doing an iOS app, and I have bought the BLEduino, which is an arduino with BLE technology built-in. The question is, do I need to program something in BLEduino? Can I just turn it on, so it can be discoverable, and then code in Xcode for my app to connect with BLEduino, and etc?

Comment: Check the Getting Started Section at http://bleduino.cc/start/ . You can upload an example sketch for example with the Arduino IDE and use the BLEduino iOS app. Don't know whether there is a sketch by default on the BLEduino. You can tried it and if not upload a demo sketch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BLEduino comes pre-loaded with the [library firmware](https://github.com/BLEduino/bleduino-firmware) (i.e. that processes all BLE communication), and the sketch for the Console module (which interacts with the library). That is, you don't need to program anything into the BLEduino to get started. Thus, yes, plug it in, and it should be discoverable.

You don't need to program anything on the iOS side either to get started. You can use the [BLEduino iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bleduino/id913043721?mt=8). The BLEduino platform (firmware library, sketches, iOS app) supports 12 different modules. Simply upload to the BLEduino [the corresponding sketch for whichever module you want to use](http://bleduino.cc/start/examples), and it will work with the provided app.

Additionally, the BLEduino app is completely [open sourced](https://github.com/BLEduino/bleduino-ios). I would suggest you play with that before doing one from scratch. That way you can see how to use the BLEduino iOS SDK.

Lastly, if you definitely want to do something completely from scratch (i.e. without the BLEduino iOS SDK), then simply make sure that your `CoreBluetooth` code complies with the [BLEduino BLE Profile](http://forum.bleduino.cc/t/service-and-characteristic-uuids-of-bleduino/107), and [packet structure](http://forum.bleduino.cc/t/what-is-the-packet-structure-for-the-bleduino-characteristics/119).

Alternatively, you can [upload your own BLE profile to the BLEduino](http://forum.bleduino.cc/t/how-do-i-modify-the-bleduino-to-put-my-own-ble-profile-services/182). In that case, you define your own UUIDs, Characteristics, and packet structure.

There's additional information on the [documentation](http://bleduino.cc/start/), and [forum](http://forum.bleduino.cc).

Comment: Where can I buy BLEduino?